# three.js 3ds file loading slow

Tags: three.js

I am using Three.js to display 3d point gene data. As part of the project I also need to display a "model" developed in 3ds. I used Blender to convert the 3ds file to jason.The file is about 7K.  I am loading the file using:

```
loader.load( "temp.js", function( geometry ) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
    scene.add( mesh ); } );
```

The code runs fine but it takes over a minute for the image to appear. Once on the screen it is fine, rotate, zoom,... Its just the initial process that seems slow. Is there a way to speed this up?

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 0):

Try to export obj from 3ds. Then use OBJLoader to load model. Should be fast.